# CakePHP auth Pluggin redirect issue

Tags: cakephp, authentication, before-filter

I am using cakephp auth Plugin .
After login what happening is .
The default log-in page is set by defining the loginAction variable in the beforeFilter function in your UsersController or AppController.
But if you have used plug-ins in your application, and if a user tries to access a controller action of a plug-in the user is redirected to an invalid page like this.

http://satyam.vakharia.com/plugin_name/users/login

BeforeFilter functionality is like this..

```
function beforeFilter() {
Security::setHash('md5');
$this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
$this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index');
$this->Auth->loginError = 'Invalid Username or Password.';
$this->Auth->authError = "You are not authorized to access.";
$this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$this->Auth->loginAction = array('plugin' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
$this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('plugin' => false, 'controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index');
$this->Auth->loginError = 'Invalid Username or Password.';
$this->Auth->authError = "You are not authorized to access.";
$this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('plugin' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
```

There.

Comment: only one thing that I have to add is 'plugin'=>false ?

Comment: Yes, try that that should fix your issue

Comment: What to do for cakephp 3 versions?